# How to upload an image to server directory using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fetch-api

I have this ajax post to the server to send some data to an SQL db :

```
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://www.example.com/main/public/actions.php",
            data: {
                name: person.name,
                age: person.age,
                height: person.height,
                weight: person.weight
            },
            success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            }

        })
```

in the server i get this data with php like this :

```
<?php

include "config.php";

if(isset ( $_REQUEST["name"] ) ) {

$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$age = $_REQUEST["age"];
$height = $_REQUEST["height"];
$weight = $_REQUEST["weight"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO persons ( name, age, height, weight )
        VALUES ( '$name', '$age', '$height', '$weight' )";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    
  echo "New person stored succesfully !";
    
  exit;
  }else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  exit;
  }
    
};

?>
```

I also have this input :

```
<input id="myFileInput" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

and in the same directory as `actions.php` i have the folder `/images`

How can i include an image ( from `#myFileInput` ) in this ajax post and save it to the server using the same query in php ?

I have searched solutions in SO but most of them are >10 years old,i was wondering if there is a simple and modern method to do it,i'm open to learn and use the fetch api if its the best practice.

Comment: I guess the "modern" method is to use the `Fetch` api in conjunction with a `FormData` object

Comment: Note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and another change you might wish to look at making would be to begin using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: For file upload in ajax, please use **FormData** (I think if you google "file upload in ajax" you get lots of examples )

Answer (score 0):

via ajax FormData you can send it . refer here . Note : data: new FormData(this) - This sends the entire form data (incldues file and input box data)

URL : https://www.cloudways.com/blog/the-basics-of-file-upload-in-php/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#form").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxupload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                //$("#preview").fadeOut();
                $("#err").fadeOut();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 'invalid') {
                    // invalid file format.
                    $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
                } else {
                    // view uploaded file.
                    $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
                    $("#form")[0].reset();
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: The above one sends the file and the data entered in text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the formData API to send your file (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

I think what you are looking for is something like that:

```
var file_data = $('#myFileInput').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);                   
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.example.com/main/public/actions.php',
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false, // Important to keep file as is
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(php_script_response){
        console.log(response);
    }
 });
```

jQuery ajax wrapper has a parameter to avoid content processing which is important for file upload.

On the server side, a vrey simple handler for files could look like this:

```
<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'];
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

?>
```

Comment: This will only send the file, but none of the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not averse to using the `fetch` api then you might be able to send the textual data and your file like this:

```
let file=document.querySelector('#myFileInput').files[0];

let fd=new FormData();
    fd.set('name',person.name);
    fd.set('age',person.age);
    fd.set('height',person.height);
    fd.set('weight',person.weight);
    fd.set('file', file, file.name );

let args={// edit as appropriate for domain and whether to send cookies
    body:fd,
    mode:'same-origin',
    method:'post',
    credentials:'same-origin'
};

let url='https://www.example.com/main/public/actions.php';

let oReq=new Request( url, args );
    
fetch( oReq )
    .then( r=>r.text() )
    .then( text=>{
        console.log(text)
    });
```

And on the PHP side you should use a prepared statement to mitigate SQL injection and should be able to access the uploaded file like so:

```
<?php

    if( isset(
        $_POST['name'],
        $_POST['age'],
        $_POST['height'],
        $_POST['weight'],
        $_FILES['file']
    )) {
    
        include 'config.php';
        
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $height = $_POST['height'];
        $weight = $_POST['weight'];
        
        
        $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp,'/path/to/folder/'.$name );
        #add file name to db????
        
        

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `persons` ( `name`, `age`, `height`, `weight` ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,? )';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$name,$age,$height,$weight);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
        
        exit( $rows ? 'New person stored succesfully!' : 'Bogus...');
    };
?>
```